# Combine 2 lines, sometimes, in large text files

Tags: vb.net, text, replace, large-files

I need to do search and replace across 2 lines of a large ascii text file, where this may occur n times (n>1000) in random places.  A text file looks like this:

```
....
StringVariable='
my contents' 
.....
```

and I want it to read:

```
....
StringVariable='my contents'
....
```

For small files, I use AllText, which works fine for small files:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(MyInputFile,  My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(MyOutputFile).Replace("='" & vbCrLf, "='"), False)
```

For large ones, AllText crashes with out of memory error.  I see posts to use ReadLine and WriteLine, and how to test strings for characters, but I am missing how to combine multiple lines 'n' times without losing my place in the file.  I guess I could split the large file into many small files carefully to allow use of AllText, and then recombine, but that seems crude.  Is there a better way?

I see how to fix the case listed above, but I have other cases (e.g, 2 CR's after a specific string) and struggling to resolve for flexible case where you want to replace a multi-line string with a variable length multi-line string.

Here is the code I used for the initial case above:

```
Private Sub RemoveCRBefore(ByVal Infile As String, ByVal Outfile As String, ByVal LookedFor As String)
    Dim Line0 As String = ""
    Dim LinedUp As String = ""
    Dim LookLong As Integer = LookedFor.Length
    Dim FirstLine As Boolean = True

    Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Infile)
        Using sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(Outfile)
            Dim Line1 As String = sr.ReadLine

            Do While (Not Line1 Is Nothing)
                If Line1.Length >= LookLong Then
                    If LookedFor = Line1.Substring(0, LookLong) And Not FirstLine Then
                        LinedUp = Line0.Replace(vbCrLf, "") & Line1
                        Line0 = LinedUp
                        FirstLine = True
                    Else
                        If FirstLine = False Then sw.WriteLine(Line0)
                        Line0 = Line1
                    End If
                Else
                    sw.WriteLine(Line0)
                    Line0 = Line1
                End If
                Line1 = sr.ReadLine
                FirstLine = False
            Loop

            sw.WriteLine(Line0)

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps try reading each line with the streamreader. Apply your Replace method against it (since you're looking for =' this won't affect the NewLine character at the end of the completed string). Write your current "fixed" line back to a secondary file using StreamWriter and setting the Append = true.

Comment: String are immutable, so trying to do all that in one line is going to generate a great many strings as new ones are created from `Replace`.

Comment: @CharlesMay - I see how to use line commands for my initial example (removing one vbCrLf before a specific string).   Not easy to extend to examples with more than 2 lines though, or similar.  I will edit my post to show my code for initial case.

Comment: fyi - I gave up and wrote 4 subroutines - one to remove vbCrLf after a string, one to remove vbCrLf  before a string, one to insert a missing vbCrLf  in middle of a string, and one to replace 2 vbCrLf 's with 1 vbCrLf after a string.   Not too slick, but I could not figure out how to be generic, so basic idea used was to read a few lines before deciding exactly how to write them.  I can't believe such specific code is of much value, but if I should post it, let me know.